# Can you use wx.Timer() function to create dynamic graphs?

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

I tried assigning a plotting function with the wx.Timer so that the graph is plotted every 1000 milliseconds. Yet, the graph is not appearing at at all.

```
class GPanel0(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.figure = Figure()
    self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
    self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.draw, self.timer)
    self.timer.Start(1000)


def draw(self, event):
    y, x=np.loadtxt('bv.txt',delimiter=',', unpack=True)
    self.axes.plot(x, y)

def ShowYourself(self):
    self.Raise()
    self.SetPosition((0,2))
    self.Fit()
    self.Show()
```

yet the graph does not plot a single set of variables at all. It seems as if the timer function does not work with plotting. 
I am pretty new to this so please do mind errors and mistakes in the question.

Comment: See the [user interface gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/) for examples of how to embed matplotlib figures inside your user interface. Eli Bendersky has also [posted some nice examples](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/).

Comment: I think you have to call `Refresh` or `Layout` or something similar method to make the changes appear on the screen.

Comment: tried refreshing but it doesnt respond. The weird part is that if i keep minimizing or maximizing the window it seems to be updating and weirdly the plot lines keep changing colours!